# dynamic sql not working . Regular sql working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating two table and trying to do `select * into` using sql and dynamic sql . I am not sure why the same query in dynamic sql is throwing me error . Can you please help

Note: I know I can use create table and insert into to make it work. But my question is why below is not working with dynamic sql

```
create table emp_info (emp_id int,sal float) 
create table emp_sal(emp_id int,sal float)

insert into emp_info values (1,1000)
insert into emp_info values (2,1000)
insert into emp_sal values (1,1000)
insert into emp_sal values (2,1000)

BEGIN   
   SELECT A.emp_id,A.sal  into  #EE_tmp
   FROM emp_info A, emp_sal B   
   WHERE A.emp_id = 1   AND A.emp_id = B.emp_id   
   select * from  #EE_tmp 
 END
```

> Result: emp_id    sal 1   1,000

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dsql varchar(10000)
    SET @dsql = ' SELECT A.emp_id,A.sal  into  #EE_tmp'
                 + ' FROM emp_info A, emp_sal B'
                 + '  WHERE A.emp_id = 1'
                 +'  AND A.emp_id = B.emp_id'    
                 EXECUTE(@dsql)      
                 select * from #EE_tmp
 END
```

Result:

> Error: #EE_tmp not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to
>   check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).

Comment: Yes it should be gone after my session.Even I made that as permanent table I am getting the error

Comment: what was the error after changing temp table to a normal table?

Comment: Why you say my execute is in wrong place. I am putting that in next to dsql formation

Comment: Same error Error: TT_1 not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).